# Add Button with link in Fancybox Manual Gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using the Fancybox plugin to show the gallery. It working good as i am able to open the pictures in gallery with the manual link.

Now I want to add the Button with some description and button will link to external page. How can i do it? Can any one help me out?

I have tried this `'title': 'This is description <a href="link.html>"<button>Buy</button></a>'` and also `'title':'This is description', link:'link.html'` Neither of them worked

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.fancy').fancybox({
    title: {
        type: 'inside'
    }
});
```

Will let you set anchors inside the title.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OhMrBigshot/ZePx5/3650/)

By the way, you shouldn't put buttons inside of links. Either use `<button>` and set a click function for it like so:

```
$('.myButton').on('click', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Or just use normal text in a link.